# New to investing, do I have to pay taxes on my ETF's interest or just when I sell it?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, etf

I recently bought one share of VUG (ETF) and it's not doing so bad so far, I made a profit of roughly 2 dollars. Do I file this in tax somewhere? Or do I only file if I sell the thing.

I can't find any helpful information on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you haven’t sold it yet, then you haven’t actually made a profit. The change in value that you see today is only a theoretical profit that could be made real if you sold it today. Tomorrow, that theoretical profit could disappear.

Comment: Note that your broker will send you a form 1099 (usually in a "combined" format listing all of the activity for the year); if it's taxable, it should be on there.

Comment: If you've only bought one share, that two dollars has a long way to go before you cover just the costs of buying (and selling) it and holding it in an account.  This doesn't change the answers below, of course, but you've made no profit yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only owe capital gains  when you realize the profits. That is, you will owe taxes for any gains in the tax year that you sell it.  You would report the gains on your tax forms and calculate the tax owed then.

One caveat (thanks @justin cave): If the ETF pays dividends, you will owe taxes on those in the year they were paid out regardless of whether you kept or sold the underlying investment.

Comment: +1.  Can you add a comment about the dividends that the ETF will produce though?

Comment: @Justin [Recent VUG distributions](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/distributions/vug) Growth funds, like the growth stocks underlying them, generally pay little if any dividends.

Answer (score 4):

In a non-tax-sheltered (i.e. retirement) account, you will possibly owe taxes on capital gains when you *sell* the investment for a profit, and "distributions", which may be classified as capital gains, dividends, etc.

I say possibly because those gains can be offset by *losses* in other investments during the same tax year. After the year is over, your broker should send you one or more "1099" statements that summarize the *total* taxable events for the year. You'll use that statement to fill out your income tax forms (or enter in the data to whatever tax software you use).

All that to say that you don't need to worry about paying taxes *now* until you start getting massive gains or dividends (thousands of dollars) that may require you to pay quarterly estimated taxes.

Comment: ETFs generally don't need to (and don't) make capital gain distributions because substantially all their asset dispositions are in-kind redemptions by APs.